# WCF Rest Service with both http and https bindings

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest, web-config

I'm trying to create a rest service that can accept both http and https traffic. The reason for this is that my company offers our customers both a hosted and non-hosted solution. In the hosted solution, all traffic goes through an F5 which strips out the SSL and forwards it to our servers in regular http.

The non-hosted solutions have their web servers handle the SSL (thus, the server is expecting https security).

The binding was originally defined like so:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

However, this did not work for our non-hosted customers. I then changed it to this

```
   <webHttpBinding>
    <binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

But, as you can guess, this did not work for our hosted customers.

Is it possible to have a WCF rest service using the .NET 4.0 framework accept both http and https traffic?

I have tried this:

```
      <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="normalRestBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="secureRestBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

with this service definition:

```
 <service name="theService" behaviorConfiguration="RestServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="normalRestEndpoint" address="" behaviorConfiguration="RestEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="normalRestBinding" contract="theContract">
      <identity>
        <dns />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint name="secureRestEndpoint" address="" behaviorConfiguration="RestEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureRestBinding" contract="theContract">
      <identity>
        <dns />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
```

Using these, I am now getting this error when trying to access the endpoint over regular http:

**Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure this out.

The code I put toward the bottom of the questions was fine.

To resolve that error message, I had to ensure that an https binding existed in IIS on the server(s) I was attempting to use this web config for.

Sorry for self-answering, but I didn't want to leave this open and somebody waste their time trying to answer it for me!

Thanks!